# What is the value of $x-y-z=\ldots$, where $x,y,z$ represents angle(s) in degree?

Tags: geometry, angle

Somebody asked me to find , $x^0-y^0-z^0= \cdots$?
He also told me the answer is $-1$. How is that? 
Or now it can be presented as 
prove that, $x^0-y^0-z^0= -1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are not angles in degrees they are numbers to the power $0$.

For $x\ne 0, x^0=1$ and that is why the answer is $-1$.